# Bootstrap-datetimepicker: end() is not a function when using find()

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError` when using `find()` to set dates to found elements.

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   $(...).find(...).data(...).end(...).find(...).data(...).date(...).end
>   is not a function

```
$('.assignees-form .assignee:last')
    .find('.start input').data('DateTimePicker').date('04/17/2017 19:50 pm').end()
    .find('.due input').data('DateTimePicker').date('04/17/2017 20:15 pm').end()
    ......
```

Works just fine when not using `end()`.

```
$('.assignees-form .assignee:last').find('.start input').data('DateTimePicker').date('04/17/2017 19:50 pm');
$('.assignees-form .assignee:last').find('.due input').data('DateTimePicker').date('04/17/2017 20:15 pm');
```

I have more than 25 elements to update and I don't want to start duplicating lines.

Any advise?

Comment: The `.date` is an extended function of jquery which is made from bootstrap. And the `.date` does not contain in jquery library which may make this happen.

Comment: Understand. But any possible tweaks to call `.end()` or return back to the element?

Comment: did you want to update the date of datetimepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jacky Shek stated in the comments [`date()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) is a function of the datetimepicker and it does not return a jQuery object, so it is not chainable.

You can cache your jQuery selector and then use `find` instead of using `end()`.

Your code could be like the following:

```
var $elem = $('.assignees-form .assignee:last');
$elem.find('.start input').data('DateTimePicker').date('04/17/2017 19:50 pm');
$elem.find('.due input').data('DateTimePicker').date('04/17/2017 20:15 pm');
```